# Publish the same Chrome extension to multiple Private domains?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am the administrator of two separate Google domains, both MyWebsite1 and MyWebsite2. Can I publish a Chrome extension so that it has Private visibility for both MyWebsite1 and MyWebsite2 (at the same Web Store URL)?

Currently in the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard under Payments & Distribution, I can only select a single domain for Private visibility.

[image]